# docker run $(pwd) command invalid in Windows

Tags: windows, docker, cmd

I have to run a simple front-end app on docker with nginx.
I'm following a tutorial that says to run in order:

```
docker build -t mytest
docker run -v $(pwd):/mnt -p 9090:9090 -w /mnt mytest ./scripts/tests.sh
```

the first command is ok, the app works fine.
When I run the second one I have an error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: create $(pwd): "$(pwd)" includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed. If you intended to pass a host directory, use absolute path.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

What is $(pwd)?

I read the doc about -v option but I don't understand the meaning of this variable.

I'm using Windows OS.

Comment: `$(pwd)` isn't a variable. It's an instruction to the shell to run the command `pwd` and substitute its contents in place. The much more efficient alternative that's a _variable_ is `$PWD` -- but this is all things supposed to be done _by your shell_ before Docker is started at all.

Comment: That you're getting this error implies that you don't _have_ a POSIX-family shell processing your command before it reaches `docker`. How are you running this command in the first place? If you're on Windows, are you using cmd.exe? PowerShell? If it's one of those you should probably be asking what the equivalent is _for that shell_, and tagging appropriately; since this isn't really a question _about Docker_ at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `cmd.exe` equivalent to `$PWD` (which is what the tutorial *should* be recommending instead of the much less efficient `$(pwd)`) is `%cd%`

Thus:

```
docker run -v %cd%:/mnt -p 9090:9090 -w /mnt mytest ./scripts/tests.sh
```

Comment: What about the last command: ./scripts/tests.sh? What is the purpose of it?

Comment: @TommyR22, it's passed to the container you're running, so what its meaning or purpose is depends on that container. _Presumably_, though, the container contains a file named `scripts/test.sh` and this is running that file.

Comment: ...mind, since your working directory in the container is `/mnt`, and the `-v` passes the current location through as `/mnt` in the container, it's presumably also expected to exist as `scripts\test.sh` on the host. But this is all presumptive; a container _could_ interpret the argument a completely different way, if it were built to.

Comment: I've created `tests.sh` inside `/mnt/scripts` but doesn't work.
this is my Dockerfile:
`#stage 1
FROM node:alpine as build
WORKDIR /mnt
COPY . .
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build
#stage2
FROM nginx:alpine as nginx
COPY --from=build /mnt/dist/exercise /usr/share/nginx/html
#CMD ["sh", "./scripts/tests.sh"]
EXPOSE 99`
when I run that command, I receve an error:
`/docker-entrypoint.sh: exec: line 38: ./script/tests.sh: not found`
if I add CMD on Dockerfile and run:
`docker run -v %cd%:/mnt -p 9090:9090 -w /mnt mytest`
the script runs, I would run by docker run.

Comment: That's a separate problem. One question to a question; this one was only about `$(pwd)`

Comment: yes sorry, I've opened new one about that:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72665619/docker-run-script-sh-by-command